# Swagger UI "Failed to fetch" when uploading a file

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

My endpoint:

```
    [HttpPost("upload")]
    public async Task Upload([FromForm]FileUploadRequest request)
    {
        using var stream = request.File.OpenReadStream();
        await _mediaService.AddMediaFile(UserId, request.MediaId, stream);
    }
```

Swagger, successfully, determines that the request needs a GUID and file:

```
public class FileUploadRequest
{
    public Guid MediaId { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

I populate the `MediaId`. Fine.

If I attempt to hit this endpoint with a `File` selected, however, I get the following error:

[image]

### Question

Why am I unable to use this Swagger file picker feature? Just to be clear - when I don't select a file it hits the endpoint just fine.

### What I've Tried

- Removing (and adding) the `[FromForm]` attribute.
- Removing HTTPS redirection (this shouldn't be an issue, Swagger is talking to my server over HTTPs it seems)
- Also ensured nothing else is happening on the server before the request is handled (i.e. nothing horrible in the constructor of the base class that would bomb out first)

### Update

Finally worked out what's causing it - if I leave the Swagger UI dormant, it's fine. But as soon as I select a file (native file picker), my server stops.

### Another Update

Even if I don't select a file, just popping open the file picker dialog but choosing to **cancel** instead (i.e. not selecting a file) causes my server to stop. I'm totally confused as there doesn't appear to be any network requests from swagger at this point.

Comment: Is your server up though? Failed to fetch is not a backend error, it's a connectivity error AFAIK.

Comment: @pneuma - this is going to sound terribly amateur - but it "just started working". I haven't changed a thing since I last ran it. Not a thing. Now it's uploading just fine. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Now it is failing again - again, not a thing has changed. It appears to bomb out - I check the solution and it has stopped running, obviously an exception somewhere I'm not seeing.

Comment: @pneuma - you were correct, the server was not running. It stops as soon as I select a file. Not a clue why, this is Swagger UI without any tweaks from me.

Comment: What's the error message on the Console tab in the browser dev tools when you run the request?

Comment: Does your server also stop if you run the request from another client e.g. Postman or via curl `curl https://localhost:44355/Media/upload -F MediaId=YOUR_UUID -F File=@YOUR_FILE` ? If so, then it's not a Swagger UI issue but an issue with your server.

Comment: @Helen - no error, and no network request, very very odd. Good point over making the request from elsewhere - I'll give that a go. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ then your problem is not the Swagger, it's your server dying before you're uploading the file. Does it log anything? If not, lower the logging level/setup proper logging. It can't possibly be related to the fact that you're selecting the file in the browser because those two apps do not communicate in any way

Comment: I created a new .net 6 api project in my VS 2022 and I copied all your code, then everything worked well in my side. According to your discussion content, it may some issue in some other places...

Comment: @TinyWang - agreed, maybe something local to my machine, some native behaviour stopping the dev server or something - but I've never seen anything like this.

Comment: yeah, but without the error messages, we can't troubleshoot this issue...

Comment: @TinyWang - there are none, I'm trying to work it out. I'll check the system event logs, that's how 'deep' this issue seems to be. There's nothing obvious (e.g. failed network requests or console errors). Nor is there anything relevant in the output window in VS.

Comment: thank you and pls kindly update the question if you got any progress.